# WordPress : display page if have special template and custom field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I would like to display, in a page,, a list of page which has:

- a custom template
- AND a custom field

I know how to display page with custom template, it works:

```
<?php $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_wp_page_template',
            'value' => 'custom-template.php'
        )
    )
);
$the_pages = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $the_pages->have_posts() ){
    while( $the_pages->have_posts() ){
        $the_pages->the_post(); ?>
        <h2><?php the_title; ?></h2>
    <?php }
} wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

But I would like to add a condition: display only if they have the custom field "hello".

Probably I should add something like this but I don't know where, I tried different things and it doesn't work.

```
array(
'key' => 'hello'
)
```

Do you have an idea? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: why are you displaying page using the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the custom field key and value to your meat query like you have done for page template:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => '_wp_page_template',
            'value'   => 'custom-template.php',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'hello',
            'value'   => '',
            'compare' => '!='
        ),
    )
);
```

Comment: I made a mistake by writing feature-it, it was an example

Comment: So something like that ? :
`<?php $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_wp_page_template',
            'value' => 'custom-template.php'
        )
        array(
       'key' => 'hello'
        )
    )
);
$the_pages = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $the_pages->have_posts() ){
    while( $the_pages->have_posts() ){
        $the_pages->the_post(); ?>
        <h2><?php the_title; ?></h2>
    <?php }
} wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php } ?>`

Comment: I Haven't tested it but I've edited my answer to show how I think the met_query should look.

Comment: Thank you. But what about if I want the post with the field "hello" filled, whatever the value ?

Comment: I've edited my answer above, if there is any value in the hello field if it's blank the page won't show. That should work if I understand you correctly.